# Arduino IDE Permision Denied For Upload, Ubuntu

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, linux

I am having issues uploading to my Arduino from the IDE on Ubuntu 18.04. The error message I have received is:

> Arduino: 1.6.10 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>   avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied

I have checked other questions similiar to this one and have tried adding myself to the dialout group running:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout username
```

and added permission to write:

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

After, when I run:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 username dialout 188, 0 jūl  2 16:09 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

However,I still get the same error message from the IDE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also have set the port in Tools to ttyUSB0

Comment: log-out and log-in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6

Comment: Are you sure it's /dev/ttyUSB0? A *real* Arduino will be /dev/ttyACM0. Maybe yours is a cheap chinese clone?

Comment: Yeah just discovered it is a CH340G chip. Any hope of still getting it to work? Have heard of people having success on Windows but haven't found any good troubleshooting for Linux.

Comment: Were you able to make it work?

Comment: No I ended up giving up and using another board I have. I have another project I am going to start in a month or so for which I am going to try to use that board so will post an update then if I figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Arduino has added a script to the install to fix this problem.  I found it after much annoyance trying to get it to work with all these suggestions.

In the arduino-1.8.8-linuxarm.tar.xz file that you download is a script called `arduino-linux-setup.sh`

run that from commandline with your user name `./arduino-linux-setup.sh <username>`

It'll ask for the root password, and then ask you to reboot.  After that you won't have any more port trouble.

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned on the official [guide for Linux](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux/), you need to run

`sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>`

with the `<username>` replaced with the username of your system.
After running this, log out and log in (or in some cases reboot the computer) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

When you run

> ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0

you have

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 username dialout 188, 0 jūl  2 16:09 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**The Problem** is you have `the dev` as `<username>`, try to change to as root

```
sudo chown root:dialout -R /dev/
```

**Note:**

One thing after your plug your USB, check your port with follow

```
ll /dev/tty*
```

if you can see my port as ttyUSB0 or with difference name (i.g ttyUSBx / ttyACMx ).
and then try to compile your sketch with following,

```
cd /path/your/arduino/installation/
$ARDUINO-DIR(pwd)
cd /path/your/sketch/
$ARDUINO-INO/arduino --verify sketch.ino --board arduino:avr:uno --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --verbose //compile your sketch.ino with arduino uno board.
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: You definitely SHOULD NOT change the ownership of every file under /dev as `chown -R` will.