# Unable to program with AVR ISP mkII under Linux

Tags: programming, isp, programmer

I just got an AVR ASP mkII external programmer and I am unsuccessfully trying to program my arduino with it.

All the settings in the IDE are correct. This is the error message that I am getting:
`avrdude: usbdev_open(): cannot open device: Permission denied`

Typing `lsusb` in a terminal, I am able to see the programmer.
`Bus 001 Device 007: ID 03eb:2104 Atmel Corp. AVR ISP mkII`

Comment: Do you have a udev rules for it (for example from [platformio](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/core/installation/udev-rules.html))? Is it working under root?

Comment: @KIIV I just opened the Arduino IDE from the Gnome GUI. Therefore I am guessing it is not root. As for udev.... I don't know much about it and I haven't touched it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino IDE Permision Denied For Upload, Ubuntu](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54098/arduino-ide-permision-denied-for-upload-ubuntu)

Comment: @thebusybee the AVRISPmkII does not create tty device. So closing as a duplicate of that question won't help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the command used for avrdude. You might need to enable the verbose output of the upload process in the preferences.

Comment: @thebusybee I am not explicitly using avrdude. I am using the AVR IDE, and I select "upload using external programmer".